# How to get the number of rows in xlrd which has data in them Python

Tags: python-3.x, excel, xlrd

I am using `xlrd` in `python3` to get the number of rows. I have an excel sheet which has `1136` rows but only few rows contains data and rest of them are empty. Below is a screenshot:

[image]

In above photo, till row 7 we have data but rest of the rows are empty. I want to get the number of rows which has data.

```
import xlrd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('Import Template-3.xlsx')
sheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)

no_of_rows = sheet.nrows
print(no_of_rows)
```

But I think the above code prints `1136` as the number of rows. Is there any function/method available through which we can only get the number of rows having data. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert only the rows those have data, then use

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)
sh = list(xl.sheet_names)

for i in sh:
    df = pd.read_excel(file,sheet_name=i, comment='#')
    print(df.count())
    df_derived = df[df['AnimalID'] == i] 
    print(df_derived.count())
    df_list = df_derived.values.tolist()
```

depending on a column of identification.